# what are the the strengths and the limitations of description logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

What are the the strengths and the limitations of description logic compared to other types of logic?

For example in terms of satisfiability, is Description Logic satisfiability decidable or not?

Comment: Welcome to the community! Please try to make questions more specific with more context to get possible answers :)

Comment: Thank you! I tried to elaborate more. please forgive me as a beginner here

Comment: To quote from [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Description_logic#First-order_logic): "Many DLs are decidable fragments of first-order logic (FOL) and are usually fragments of two-variable logic or guarded logic."

Comment: Does this mean that DL satisifiability is decidable?

Comment: The wikipedia page linked in @NoahSchweber's comment is about many description logics. Your question seems to presuppose one particular DL but doesn't indicate which one you have in mind. If you're asking about all DL's, then the quote in Noah's comment suggests that many are decidable but some are not.